# JPA DTO <-> Entity transition , when entities have relationship

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm developing spring boot application using JPA

I'm using nested entities , entities are connected by multiple mapping relationships

The problem is that ,
while making dto to entity , circular reference occurs.

For example , I have one to many relationship between User Entity and Review Entity
In Dto class, I implemented toEntity method like below.

userDto, ReviewDto

```
 public UserInfo toEntity(){
        return User.builder()
                .userInfoId(userInfoId)
                ....
                .reviewDto(new ReviewDto(this.review.toEntity())
}

public Review toEntity(){
            return Review.builder()
                    .userInfoId(userInfoId)
                    ....
                    .reviewDto(new ReviewDto(this.review.toEntity())
    }
```

abvode code makes circular reference or stack overflow when calling it

I want to get advice of best practice for DTO to entity method when having relationship between entities